# Cotravariance in interface functions with generic parameters - why does on of theses functions compile?

Tags: typescript, interface, covariance

I've been using typescript for a while now but didn't yet dive into it's deep dark corners. Now I'm trying to refactor my code with strict mode, but ran into code that - I believe - shouldn't compile. See my code, explanation and question below:

### Code

```
class Base { }

class Child extends Base {
    public name: string = 'childName';
}

interface Foo<T> {
    // 1) fails to compile
    foo: (value: T) => void; 
    // 2) compiles but crashes
    // foo(value: T): void; 
}

const childFoo: Foo<Child> = {
    foo: (value: Child): void => console.log(value.name.toLowerCase()), // using 2) crash happens here
};

const baseFoo: Foo<Base> = childFoo; // using 1) error occurs here

baseFoo.foo(new Base());
```

(See also on [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCkFNoG8C+BYAUF0kYGEALASxABNoEAPAFwQDsyZ4IlktpPoAHAVwCMQxYNHpgAtggBc0CDQBOxegHNoAXmgByYCXIA5CQk0BuLBmyYldeQDMwwJADEA9s4A8AFQB8KDlwD0-tAAjACU0HakMDTO0MDO4tykCH6cNq4yABQAbmAgvNLQHuFqPtnOxGTG0KnQgdAATOHxickw-Lw0cfKQhAgQtfXpzjl5BTLFMuWV1WZYOM70cnG6ZC7OMutuRKRkPhrsmFwRGdCj+YU75KFTFRSlcYsQziAIAHQgzsrnBW9ikm8YgAZZwAdwQ8nwiEyoVCABozKYLPEll1+Ih1ptXG4WAh9itduskVh0ax1m9hpl6AhQXBobDjEA))

### Observed behaviour

Using function 1) yields the following error:

```
Type 'Foo<Child>' is not assignable to type 'Foo<Base>'.
  Property 'name' is missing in type 'Base' but required in type 'Child'
```

This is to be expected, because `Foo<Base>.foo` requires a function that can handle any `Base`, but `Foo<Child>.foo` is a function that can only handle a more specialized type (`Child`), right?

Using function 2) compiles and crashes:

```
Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
```

While the crash is to be expected, I didn't expect it to compile at all.

### Expected behaviour

Neither 1) nor 2) should compile with `strict = true`.

---

**Why does this piece of code compile when function 2) is used instead of 1)?**